# Possible to call Oracle FUNCTION from .Net using Enterprise Library?

Tags: .net, oracle, enterprise-library

I have the following Oracle function:

```
function get_job_no return number is
        V_job_no number;
      begin
         select appwork.tlm_corphier_job.nextval into V_job_no from dual;
         return V_job_no;
      end get_job_no;
```

PLEASE NOTE:
1) This is a FUNCTION, not a procedure
2) This is returning a NUMBER, not a VARCHAR
3) I happen to be using System.Data.OracleClient rather than Oracle.DataAccess.Client (due to another issue I was having) but a solution with either would be fine.

I am trying to call this from VB.Net using the MS enterprise library like so:

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
Imports System.Data.OracleClient
    Public Function GetNextJobNumber() As Object
        Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
        Dim myresult As Object = Nothing
        Using cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("CORPHIER_PKG.get_job_no")
            Dim retval As New Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter("retval", GetType(System.Data.OracleClient.OracleNumber))
            retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
            cmd.Parameters.Add(retval)
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd)
            myresult = retval.Value
        End Using
        Return myresult
    End Function
```

I get the following error:

System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a RuntimeType to a Decimal. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter.SetCoercedValueInternal(Object value, MetaType metaType)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameterBinding.PrepareForBind(OracleConnection connection, Int32& offset)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this seems to work:

```
Public Function GetNextJobNumber() As Object
    Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()
    Using cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("CORPHIER_PKG.get_job_no")
        db.AddParameter(cmd, "retval", DbType.Int32, 0, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, True, 0, 0, String.Empty, DataRowVersion.Current, Convert.DBNull)
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd)
        Return db.GetParameterValue(cmd, "retval")
    End Using
End Function
```